# Align elements using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align this 4 elements and they are not correctly aligned. I'm using bootstrap.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" <div class="row">
  <h3>Environments</h3>
  <div class="well">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>sadsadsaf</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:72">72%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this? Also, I've added the delete button based on the amount of names in the database. When I press the Delete button how do I know what's the name associated with the delete button?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the margins on your elements, as they have varying margin-top/bottom which is giving you alignment trouble.

Comment: how do you know they have different margins? I'm only using bootstrap

Comment: Inspect the elements using dev tools. You can see `.checkbox` has a margin top and bottom, your progress bar has margin bottom too.

Answer (score 0):

add those at col-md-3 or set an another class

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
```

and then set width